# How can I process images with OpenCV 3.2 with CUDA?

Tags: c++, opencv

How can I use gpu accelerated functions in OpenCV 3.2 with CUDA? What should be passed as a two first arguments into

```
void cv::cuda::bilateralFilter  (   InputArray      src,
        OutputArray     dst,
        int     kernel_size,
        float   sigma_color,
        float   sigma_spatial,
        int     borderMode = BORDER_DEFAULT,
        Stream &    stream = Stream::Null() 
    )
```

I think it should be type cv::Mat from imread function, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a cv::Mat can be used as the first and second argument to that function.

InputArray is the proxy class for passing read-only input arrays into OpenCV functions. See [InputArray](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=inputarray#InputArray)

OutputArray is very similar to InputArray except that it is used for input/output and output function parameters. See [OutputArray](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?#outputarray)

Comment: Can it be also GpuMat (from cv::cuda)? How can I convert Mat made by imread into GpuMat?